# How to set $argv to an empty list?

Tags: fish

I want to manipulate $argv and pass it on to another fish function. It is simple enough to trim it as follows:

```
switch $value
case a
    set argv $argv[2..-1]
case b
    set argv $argv[3..-1]
end

call_function $argv
```

But how can I set it to an empty list?

I don't want to `set --erase argv` because I do actually want to access the variable.

I tried `set argv $argv[]` but then `count $argv` returns 1. (And I may rely on `count` later -- unless there is a better way to *test* for emptiness?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set argv
```

You don't actually need $argv to get to an empty list at all - the empty list is just the absence of arguments.